# Remove non-numeric value from SQL Select statement along with ending decimal point

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an application version column in one of my tables. Most of the values are standard versions, such as 2020.2.0, but some have pre-release tags on them (2020.2.0.PR).

The following returns the latest entry in the table:

```
SELECT version
from dbo.server_log_entry
where server_log_entry_id = (SELECT MAX(server_log_entry_id) from dbo.server_log_entry)
```

In this case, it returns:

> 2020.2.0.PR

I'm working on a script that will compare the latest version in the DB table to a version in a file to make sure the two are compatible. The script takes the version in the file and converts it to a [version] object. I'd like to have powershell query against the database and pull the value to a version object, however I'm having some trouble removing the '.'  before the PR tag. Currently I have:

```
DECLARE @databaseVersion NVARCHAR(30)
SET @databaseVersion = (SELECT version from dbo.server_log_entry where server_log_entry_id = (SELECT MAX(server_log_entry_id) from dbo.server_log_entry))
SELECT LEFT(SUBSTRING(@databaseVersion, PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', @databaseVersion), 8000),
    PATINDEX('%[^0-9.-]%', SUBSTRING(@databaseVersion, PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', @databaseVersion), 8000) + 'X') -1)
```

This will give me a value of

> 2020.2.0.

I'd like to remove the ending period so the query returns

> 2020.2.0

however I'm not quite sure how to do that, or if I'm going about this the incorrect way.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: I've added a bit more clarification. Let me know if there's any other info that would help.

Comment: If the only suffix you need to remove out of all the tags is ".PR", then perhaps look for that in your pattern, thus `PATINDEX('%.PR%', version)`. This will give the index position of that match, which can be wrapped in a `SUBSTRING` or `LEFT` string manipulation function.

Not sure if you need to escape the dot character.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps `REPLACE( ver, '.PR','')`

```
SELECT replace( version, '.PR','')
from dbo.server_log_entry
where server_log_entry_id = (SELECT MAX(server_log_entry_id) from dbo.server_log_entry)
```

Answer (score 0):

After some trial/error, I found that the following works how I need it to

```
"SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING([version], 0, CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%.[^0-9.]%', [version]) <> 0 THEN PATINDEX('%.[^0-9.]%', [version]) ELSE 100 END) FROM dbo.server_log_entry
```

Comment: Maybe you should mark your own answer as 'answer to this question'? or, as an alternative you could do `SUBSTRING(@version,0,PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%', @version)-1)` To find a letter, and return everything before that letter (-1 to delete the '.')

Answer (score 0):

You can use REVERSE with CHARINDEX to get the result.

```sql
declare @databaseVersion VARCHAR(100) = '2020.2.0.PR'
SELECT REVERSE(RIGHT(REVERSE(@databaseVersion),
LEN(@databaseVersion)-CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(@databaseVersion))))
```

> 2020.2.0